# Creating \simrightarrow with ooalign

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols, unicode-math, scale

I would like to have a command `\simrightarrow`, that is, a `\rightarrow` with a `\sim` over it. Stealing [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset) from @egreg, I got:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

  \newcommand{\simrightarrow}{\mathrel{\ooalign{
     $\to$\cr
     \hidewidth\raise.3em\hbox{$\sim\mkern3mu$}\cr
    }
  }
}


\begin{document}
\( M \simrightarrow N \)
\end{document}
```

However, the tilde is still too big. How can I scale it down?

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489465/how-can-i-force-resized-mathmode-symbols-to-respect-fontsize-changes/489467#489467

Comment: or from what you have perhaps `$\scriptstyle\sim`  ? but as you are using `unicode-math` anyway then using `\similarrightarrow` seems most natural as that is a single glyph not an oalign construct

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will check your recommendations. Unfortunately many fonts (including Latin Modern) don't contain `\similarrightarrow`. That's why I got into `\ooalign`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did not try out `\scriptstyle` because I did not expect it to behave correctly under scaling (`\simrightarrow_{\simrightarrow}`) but it seems, it actually does. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have used this approach: the use of the `scalerel` package with the option `\scaleobj{.5}{\sim}` to decrease the size of `\sim`. I have searched a good compromise between the dimension of `\sim` and `\to`. After I have edited a little your code. Here there is the output and the MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{scalerel}
  \newcommand{\simrightarrow}{\mathrel{\ooalign{
     $\to$\cr
     \hidewidth\raise.3em\hbox{$\scaleobj{.5}{\sim}\mkern7mu$}\cr
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\( M \simrightarrow N \)
\end{document}
```

**Addendum: 12-april-2020**

With `stix` package there is the exact symbol without to use `\ooalign` if you prefer like suggested by @David Carlisle.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
$a \similarrightarrow n$
\end{document}
```

[image]